# Integrating Okta with Windows ACS

Tags: acs, okta

1. We implement a web application and host in Azure. Then we want to use the SSO feature which is supported by Microsoft Azure ACS. The Condition to view our Website is that users just need to provide the email address throughout login to IdP. When we implement and configure Web application, we do follow all the instructions on the website as below
   http://blog.2mas.xyz/configuring-windows-azure-active-directory-access-control/
2. For now, we can configure and use Window LiveID, Azure AD to login into our Website.
3. We have a further requirement that our site should support to login SSO from custom IdP which supports SAML 2.0 such as Okta.
4. Our current issues: When import the SAML 2.0 XML file to ACS, it does not understand this XML file

Please give us some suggestion to use Azure ACS and okta in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You might find the following helpful: https://www.okta.com/identity-101/integrating-sso-for-azure-ad